# After Visual Studio 2015 installation, hard drives seem to be locked

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows 2012 system with Visual Studio 2010 installed. It worked fine on this system. Today I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on it. After installation, when I try to open existing solutions with Visual Studio 2010, the loading becomes very slow. Also, I am not able to save any modified files in the solutions. It seems that all the solution folders and files have become read-only. When I tried to change the attribute in Explorer, I was shown "You will need to provide administrator persmissions to change these attributes", even though I already logged in as administrator.

When I tried to save an ordinary text file, I was also not able to because some process is locking it. The same thing happens to C:\ as well.

Also, I notice that if I right click and select "New" from the pop-up menu in Explorer, the only option is "Folder" (this only happens for D:\ and not C:).

What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems that the problem has to do with policy change of the login ID. When I right-click and run Visual Studio 2012 or notepad, and chose "Run as Administrator", I am then able to save the modified files. So even though my login ID is in Administrator group, it is not really an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The local security policy was changed when I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. In Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options, "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" was changed to "Enabled". All I needed to do was to change it back to "Disabled" and then restart the system. The problems described disappeared after that.